# Custom NSTableHeaderCell crashes when the table is resized

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstableheadercell

My application crashes when I create a custom `NSTableHeaderCell` for my `NSTableView` that does nothing except store a single optional of type `NSFont`. The table view draws fine the first time, but the app crashes when the table view is resized.

I have reduced the problem down to the presence of the `NSFont` optional.

```
class MyTableHeaderCell: NSTableHeaderCell {
    var myFont: NSFont?
}
```

I create a `MyTableHeaderCell` for each column in the table, e.g.,

```
        for (index, tc) in tableView.tableColumns.enumerated() {
            let v = MyTableHeaderCell(textCell:  "Title")
            v.myFont = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
            tc.headerCell = v
        }
```

This likely has to do with the table view creating and destroying cells, but I am at a loss.
If I simply use the `font` field of `NSTableHeaderCell`, the font gets changed back to the default after resizing the table view, hence the `myFont` field.

When the table view is resized, it appears that the value `myFont` gets trashed. Playing around with this, the app also crashes without even drawing the table view if I attempt to store a custom `NSColor` object instead of the `NSFont`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I added some additional debugging and it appears that the table header for the last column in the table is getting copied and released over and over and that appears to be the source of the crash. None of the other column headers are ever copied.

Comment: If I add an additional column to the table that does not have my custom header, everything works as expected.